# How to initialize text_field tag in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am reading Steve Holzner's [Beginning ruby on rails](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470069155) book these days but I found some content seems to be out of date.

I met a problem now that such a statement `<%= start_form_tag ({:action => “at”}, {:method => “post”}) %>` and `<%= text_field_tag (“text1”, “”, {“size” => 30}) %>` is wrong.

Could any body tell me how to correct them or tell me somewhere I could find the documentations about initializing such helper method.

Comment: That is very out of date - start_form_tag was removed in rails 2 if I remember correctly, so the book must be written against rails 1.x. A lot has changed since then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully the following are helpful:

1. [start_form_tag is now form_tag](http://p2p.wrox.com/book-beginning-ruby-rails/67374-chapter-5-start_form_tag-now-form_for.html)
2. [text_field_tag usage examples](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag)

On a related note, I would recommend using an up-to-date tutorial like [Rails Tutorial book](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) instead of the outdated `Beginning Ruby on Rails` book.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Is the book you recommended free for on line reading?

Answer (score 0):

> form_tag ({:action => “at”}, {:method => “post”}) %>  <%= text_field_tag (“text1”, “”, {“size” => 30}) %>.

This should be working one